# fsolve from scipy.optimize fails

Tags: python, scipy, solver

I am trying to compute the roots of a vectorvalued functions, but the solution I get from fsolve is entirely wrong. I do get the warning: 175: RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the improvement from the last ten iterations.
warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)

Here comes the working example:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


def AMOC(amoc_state,
         gamma= 1/0.34,
         theta = 1,
         mu = 7.5,
         sigma = 0.85):
    T = amoc_state[0]
    S = amoc_state[1]
    dT = -gamma * (T-theta) - T * (1+ mu*np.abs(T-S)) 
    dS = sigma-S*(1+mu*np.abs(T-S))
    return (dT, dS) 

test = fsolve(AMOC, (0.8,0.3), 2.3,xtol = 1e-7, factor = 0.1, maxfev = 1000)
```

this gives me `test = array([0.57372733, 0.47660354])` which is obviously no root of the AMOC function since

`AMOC((0.57372733, 0.47660354), gamma = 2.3)`
returns (-0.01121948095040759, 0.026224895476309684)

any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: FYI: A different initial guess gives a good result: with `test = fsolve(AMOC, (0.5, 1.0), 2.3, xtol=1e-7, factor=0.1, maxfev=1000)`, `AMOC(test, 2.3)` returns `(1.454392162258955e-14, 1.1657341758564144e-14)`.

Comment: One possible source of difficulty is your use of `np.abs(T-S)`.  This function is not differentiable at `T == S`.   `fsolve` is a wrapper of the MINPACK function HYBRD, which uses a numerically computed Jacobian.  The Jacobian will be incorrect in the vicinity of the points where `T == S`.

Comment: In addition to Warren's comment, it's worth mentioning that `abs` is not differentiable, so you should be careful here.

Comment: Try the approach used in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69759905/solve-a-non-linear-system-of-equations?noredirect=1#comment123319472_69759905

Comment: Thank you guys. This all makes sense. I had tried several initial conditions but didn't come close to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the `abs` function is not differentiable and so is your function `AMOC`. This is important since `fsolve`s underlying algorithm uses the derivative information in order to solve `F(x) = 0` and thus, assumes that the function `F` is differentiable.

However, as a workaround you can replace `abs(x)` by the smooth approximation `sqrt(x**2 + 1.0e-4)`:

```py
def AMOC(amoc_state, gamma= 1/0.34, theta = 1, mu = 7.5, sigma = 0.85):
    T, S = amoc_state
    smooth_abs = np.sqrt((T-S)**2 + 1.0e-4)
    dT = -gamma * (T-theta) - T * (1+ mu*smooth_abs) 
    dS = sigma-S*(1+mu*smooth_abs)
    return np.array((dT, dS))
```

Next, you can try another initial guess as Warren already mentioned. Otherwise, you can solve the problem as equivalent minimization problem by means of `scipy.optimize.minimize`. In my experience, the solvers are a bit more robust:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

res = minimize(lambda x: np.sum(AMOC(x, 2.3)**2), x0=(0.8,0.3))
```

yields the solution `array([2.25836418e-01, 1.38576534e-06])`.